# Cannot delete strange ACL for samba server

Tags: acl, samba

I have a samba shared directory //dc/documents. However it has strange ACL `ACL:S-1-22-2-0:ALLOWED/0x0/` which I can see but cannot delete.

here you can see it's listed properly but without a user name

```
$ smbcacls //dc/documents / -U "MYDOMAIN\admin"
Password for [MYDOMAIN\admin]:
REVISION:1
CONTROL:SR|DP
OWNER:MYDOMAIN\Domain Users
GROUP:MYDOMAIN\Domain Users
ACL:Everyone:ALLOWED/OI|CI/
ACL:CREATOR OWNER:ALLOWED/OI|CI|IO/FULL
ACL:CREATOR GROUP:ALLOWED/OI|CI|IO/READ
ACL:S-1-22-2-0:ALLOWED/0x0/
ACL:MYDOMAIN\Domain Users:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
```

and when I try to delete it a strong error occurs

```
$ smbcacls //dc/documents / -U "MYDOMAIN\admin" -D "ACL:S-1-22-2-0:ALLOWED/0x0/ "
Password for [MYDOMAIN\admin]:
ACE 'S-1-22-2-0:ALLOWED/0x0/ ': bad permission value at ' '
```

However deleting / adding other ACLs do not have any problem. And I suspect because of this strange ACL, I cannot even change the ACLs from Windows either. It would simply crash explorer if I click on the "Security" tab of the shared directory's properties dialog.

Now I'm stuck here, any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do a --set for the domain admin user.

```
smbcacls  //dc/documents / -U admin%password --set=ACL:DOMAIN\\admin:ALLOWED/"OI|CI"/CHANGE
```

You should delete all ACL's and start from scratch.

This fixes the windows lock in the security tab for the folder.